# Layout looks different on 2.2 and 4.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have a layout which looks very nice on Android 4.0 and 4.1:

[image]

And it looks like this on Android 2.2

[image]

Here is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date_month"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Sep"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date_day"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="26"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="40dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date_year"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="2012"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see the TextViews on the ImageView are different placed on the different versions.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it work for all android devices screens

if you do not use the image in your code, put it directly as background
 of your FrameLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar"
             >

            <!--
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/calendrier" />
            -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_month"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Dec"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_day"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="40dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_year"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="2012"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason is not in the version of the phone, whether it is 4.0 or 2.2. The problem is on different densities and widths of the screens. In android there are this kind of problems because of the different screen sizes and different manufacturers. And unfortunately `dp` measurement does not work as expected

To enable your application to support these kind of things you should read, if you haven't already, the android docs in the section for "Supporting multiple screens".

In your case you should create a `dimen.xml` file and move all your values that are in `dp` in there. A following example would make it clearer:

in dimen.xml:

```
...
<dimen name="big_size">90dp</dimen>
...
```

in the layout.xml:

```
...
layout_width="@dimen/big_size"
...
```

The default `dimen.xml` file should be inside values and then you should create subfolders , like `values-mdpi/`, of values regarding the different densities you want to support. And in there you should have different `dimen.xml` files.

In the values-mdpi/ folder the dimen.xml file would be:

```
...
<dimen name="big_size">60dp</dimen>
...
```

Notice that there is the same name but different value. Android would understand by the density of the screen and take the value that is more appropriate. For more information read the documentation I added before.

Comment: I +1'ed your comment because you are of course right with the multiple screen support. Thanks alot for your help. ABDOU's answer was working great though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that will work or not, but if I were you, I would not use imageview for this. I would use layout and set that image as its background.

Comment: Yes this is also fine. but what is the problem with ImageView?

Comment: I think problem is you add some view inside the imageview. it is designed to show images not to contain views.